# Change how often the cron job for PHP's internal garbage collection runs

Tags: php, cron, schedule

I want to modify the cron job at /etc/cron.d/php that runs PhP's garbage collector every half an hour at xx:09 and xx:39.

This is the content of the cron job.

```
# Look for and purge old sessions every 30 minutes 
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d run/systemd
/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi
```

I tried to change the minutes in the cron file to 09,19,29,39,49,59 so that it would run every 10 minutes instead of 30 minutes, but it does not look like it is working even after restarting the cron service, and then trying to restart Ubuntu itself.

I am trying to test some session related code and I don't want to wait 30 minutes for the garbage collector to run and expire sessions past their max life. It would not work to destroy the session in the code myself.

Any idea how I can make the PhP garbage collector cron run every 10 minutes?

My Ubuntu is 20.04 LTS running in Windows 10 Hyper-V.
PHP is 7.4

Answer (score 0):

You can change the cron job as below for every 10 minutes

```
*/10 * * * * root   [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please mark it as an answer if it helped you.